# Nested user controls events

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, events

I'm trying to understand how I can expose an event in this situation:

- Class C has an event E
- Class B instance an object of class C
- Class A instance an object of class B

When the event is raised from class C, is possible to manage it directly from class A?

```
Public Class C

    Public Event E()

    Public Sub Function_of_C()

         RaiseEvent E()

    End Sub

End Class


Public Class B

    Public WithEvents m_C as new C

End Class


Public Class A

    Public WithEvents m_B as new B

    Private Sub Function_of_A() Handles m_B.m_C.E '<-- Doesn't work

        'Do something

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Class B is supposed to be the sole consumer of the events from Class C.  You need Class B to raise its own event to "forward" it out to Class A.  What you have "doesnt Work" because the `m_C.E` part is not an event defined in B

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I wander if there was a better way to do that, but I understand there isn't one. So when there are a lot of event to forward throught multiple classes, the only solution is to repeat the events for each class or change the structure at all. I understand it right?

Comment: Or rethink how the thing is constructed.  If B creates an instance of C, B should be the consumer of C's events.  B may do something as a result of the event and possibly raise a new event, but If A needs to know the nitty-gritty of what is going on in C, then perhaps B and C ought to be instanced/used by A to make things simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the comment to your question. You need to bubble up the event in class B when it receives from C.

```
Sub Main

    Dim test = new A()
End Sub

Public Class C
    Public Event E()
    Public Sub Function_of_C()
         RaiseEvent E()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class B
    Public WithEvents m_C as new C
    Public Event E()
    Public Sub FnB() Handles m_C.E
        Console.WriteLine("In B received Event from C")
        RaiseEvent E()
    End Sub

    Public Sub TriggerC()
        Console.WriteLine("In B TriggerC, call C.Function_Of_C")
        m_C.Function_Of_C()
    End Sub
End Class


Public Class A

    Public WithEvents m_B as new B

    Private Sub Function_of_A() Handles m_B.E
        Console.WriteLine("In A received Event from B")
    End Sub

    public Sub New()
        Console.WriteLine("In A constructor, call B.TriggerC")
        m_b.TriggerC()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a supplement to [Steve's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197518/steve) answer, here's an example of the common design pattern to forward events:

```
Public Class Doorbell

    Public Event Ding As EventHandler

    Protected Overridable Sub OnDing(e As EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent Ding(Me, e)
    End Sub

    Friend Sub RaiseDing()
        Me.OnDing(EventArgs.Empty)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class House
    Implements IDisposable

    Public Event DoorbellDing As EventHandler

    Public Property Doorbell() As Doorbell
        Get
            Return Me.m_doorbell
        End Get
        Set(value As Doorbell)
            If (Not value Is Me.m_doorbell) Then
                Me.UnookDoorbell()
                Me.m_doorbell = value
                Me.HookDoorbell()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        Me.UnookDoorbell()
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleDoorbellDing(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Me.OnDoorbellDing(e)
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnDoorbellDing(e As EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent DoorbellDing(Me, e)
    End Sub

    Private Sub HookDoorbell()
        If (Not Me.m_doorbell Is Nothing) Then
            AddHandler Me.m_doorbell.Ding, AddressOf Me.HandleDoorbellDing
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub UnookDoorbell()
        If (Not Me.m_doorbell Is Nothing) Then
            RemoveHandler Me.m_doorbell.Ding, AddressOf Me.HandleDoorbellDing
        End If
    End Sub

    Private m_doorbell As Doorbell

End Class
```